# Find the AVG DATEDIFF of a group of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns:
Customer_ID and Transaction_Date

I'm trying to find how often a customer makes a transaction, so I need to know the DATEDIFF between each row with the same Customer_ID and then perform an AVG on them.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `transaction_date`'s type `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or other?

Comment: Do you care about the time since the most recent trnsaction?

Comment: @TheImpaler It is a DATETIME

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is arithmetic on the `max()` and `min()`:

```
select customer_id, 
       sum(datediff(day, min(Transaction_Date), max(Transaction_Date))) * 1.0 / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0) as avg_time
from t
group by customer_id;
```

That is, the average transaction time is the total transaction time divided by one less than the number of transactions.  This does not include the time from the most recent transaction.

You can visualize this:

```
1----------2------------------3-------4
```

The average is:

```
((4 - 3) + (3 - 2) + (2 - 1)) / 3
```

All the intermediate terms cancel out.

Comment: `GROUP BY customer_id` ?